# Communication to SharePoint server is canceled. (error)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am trying to host my app in Office365 but it stops on either clicking `Yes` or `No` in a prompt.

[image: Prompt Image]

When i click `No`

[image: No]

When i click `Yes`

[image: Yes]

What could be the reason?

Comment: Is that issue closed ?