# Visual Studio and SharePoint online connection

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I recently began experiencing an issue with connecting my Visual Studio SharePoint add in projects to SharePoint online. Others ([here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195005/sharepoint-development-url-visual-studio), [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/79a6de1d-36cd-4068-a570-35890a49528f/unable-to-login-in-sharepoint-online), and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159727/communication-to-sharepoint-server-is-canceled-error)) have also reported similar behavior; however, I have been unable to find a solution. My issue is as follows:
Periodically I will log in to my VM and start working on a SharePoint add in project, and when I attempt to debug I get the prompt:

[image]

It will keep asking me this until I switch to offline mode, in which case I can’t deploy my app to my development site.
If I don't switch to offline mode I get the deployment error:

"Communication with the SharePoint server is cancelled."

I’ve also noticed that when I try to create a new SharePoint add in project, when I set up the configuration to my development site I get the following error when trying to connect to SharePoint online:

“Visual studio can't connect to your SharePoint site to determine its version. Please choose the version of SharePoint you want to target from the option above”.

When I am able to connect to SharePoint, I’m asked for my credentials instead of the error above. (Server side issue?)

Things I’ve double checked:

1. Running VS as an admin
2. I'm an admin to the site collection (and dev site)
3. I've check the site url (https)
4. Server connection is "online"
5. Developer site was created with the dev template
6. I have Office developer tools installed
7. I've rebooted my VM
8. I've reinstalled Visual Studio 2019 Professional
9. I’ve tried setting LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled to true (it has worked with both true and false)
10. I’ve checked the clock time on my VM is the same
11. I've created a new developer site from scratch

Again, this issue comes and goes without any changes to SharePoint online or my project settings, so I’m at a loss at how to fix this issue (waiting a few days to work on my projects isn’t really an option).
Any advise on this issue or how to get more detailed deployment errors would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is Modern Authentication disabled?

Comment: Modern Authentication is turned on

Comment: I believe that is the issue. The wizard/F5 deployment isn't compatible with Modern Auth -- had this discussion on Twitter a few weeks back.

Comment: This setting has not changed since I started developing my add ins.